# android animating buttons from offscreen bottom to onscreen are blank

Tags: android, animation, button, off-screen

I have a RelativeLayout container with 5 Buttons on it.

When I use a TranslationAnimation from offscreen (below the screen), the buttons are blank until the animation is done. At the end of the animation, I explicitly draw the buttons and they appear in the correct locations.

I also have a similar container and buttons that I animated onscreen from the right offscreen. This container shows all of the buttons during the animation and after as I expect it to.

Also, when I animate the first set of buttons down to their offscreen location below, they are visible during the entire animation.

The problem only happens when animating from below the screen to onscreen.